# Symfony5: How do I set a custom method if unallowed method is used

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5, symfony5.4

My Route is a POST route. What I want is that if someone makes a GET request then it should give my own custom JSON message instead of the below one. I even did the following but the code is crashing at the router-related file level:

```
MethodNotAllowedException  MethodNotAllowedHttpException
HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed
No route found for "GET http://localhost:8000/api/doSearch.json": Method Not Allowed (Allow: POST)
```

[image]

```
try {
            // Check whether the request is POST or not
            if(!$request->isMethod('POST')) {
                    $isError = true;
                    $errorString = "Method Not Allowed: Only POST requests are allowed for this resource";
                    $httpCode = 405;
            }
       } catch(MethodNotAllowedHttpException $mna) {
            $isError = true;
            $errorString = "Method Not Allowed";
       }
```

Comment: My first thought would be to just allow the GET in the route signature, and then do your error logic as-is

Comment: It looks like you probably have debug on, which would show this page. You can [customize your error pages](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html). It shows 404 and 403, but you can probably create a 405 page.

Comment: Can you post the route definition, you probably have defined only POST for your route and not GET as well?